# How to identify the current page in a custom wordpress navigation menu code

Tags: wordpress

I am building a custom navigation menu in WordPress, where I have 2 level of depth; parent and direct child sub items. Some items are leaf though.

I want all parent items to have no url so that I can add a JS dropdown functionality.

The code below successfully builds the menu I desire, however, I need to identify the current page in order to add a convenient CSS class such as .current-page or .current-parent-page. In addition, if I am on a child page or item, I need to identify the current parent and the current item as well; the same as if I am using wp_nav_menu. My current code is:

```
<?php
global $post;
$the_post_ID = $post->ID;

/*global $wp_query;
$page_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$page_id     = $wp_query->get_queried_object_id();*/



if( ($locations =get_nav_menu_locations()) && isset($locations['primary']) ):
   $primary_nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $locations['primary'] );
   $primary_nav_menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $primary_nav_menu->term_id, array( 'order' => 'DESC' ) ); ?>

<ul class="off-canvas-list site-menu-list">

  <?php foreach( (array) $primary_nav_menu_items as $nav_item ):

  /* get page id by using menu item object id */
  $nav_item_id = get_post_meta( $nav_item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );

  /* set up a page object to retrieve page data */
  $page = get_page( $nav_item_id );
  $link = get_page_link( $nav_item_id );

  if( ! $nav_item->menu_item_parent ) {  /* this nav item has no parent */

    /* try to retrieve its child nav items */
    /* check function get_nav_menu_item_children() in functions.php */
    $child_nav_items = array();
    $child_nav_items = get_nav_menu_item_children( $nav_item->ID, $primary_nav_menu_items, false );

    if( empty( $child_nav_items ) ): /* nav item has no children - it is a leaf; it has a link url */?>
      <li class="????">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>"><?php echo $nav_item->title; //$page->page_title; ?></a>
      </li>
    <?php else: // nav item has children nav items - construct a sub menu ?>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <?php /* on mobile, it becomes a label button - do not include its url */?>
        <a href="#" class="ic-font"><?php echo $nav_item->title;//$page->post_title; ?></a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        <?php 
          foreach ( (array) $child_nav_items as $child_nav_item ): 
            // get page id from using menu item object id
            $child_nav_item_id = get_post_meta( $child_nav_item->ID, '_menu_item_object_id', true );

            // set up a page object to retrieve page data
            $child_nav_page = get_page( $child_nav_item_id );
            $child_nav_page_link = get_page_link( $child_nav_item_id );?>

            <li class="???">
              <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $child_nav_page_link ); ?>"><?php echo $child_nav_item->title; //$child_nav_page->post_title; ?></a>
            </li>
          <?php endforeach;?>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <?php endif; ?>

  <?php } /* this nav item has no parent */ ?>

<?php endforeach; /* loop through the primary_nav_menu_items */ ?>

</ul>

<?php endif; /* locations */ ?>
```

I tried to use `$nav_item->object_id` and compare it to the current post ID but that didn't work. I tried `is_page($nav_item->object_id)` as well but didn't work.

Your help is appreciated.